# T-SQL OPENJSON error when calling stored procedure from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, json, entity-framework, t-sql

It's working fine when I execute this with the json from SQL Server Management Studio. But the issue is when I try to call the stored procedure from C# using Entity Framework's `FromSqlRaw` method.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertWithTSQL]
    @json nvarchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Student (ID, Name, RollNo, Class, Age) 
        SELECT 
            ID, Name, RollNo, Class, Age 
        FROM 
            OPENJSON (@json) 
        WITH
            (ID int '$.Id',
             Name NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Name',
             RollNo int'$.RollNo',
             Class NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Class',
             Age int '$.Age')
END
```

Here is my C# code:

```
public IActionResult Create(Student student)
{
        //List<object> obj = new List<object>();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);
        var stringToSend = json.ToString();
        stringToSend = stringToSend.Insert(0,"'[");
        stringToSend = stringToSend.Insert(stringToSend.Length, "]'");
        var param = new SqlParameter("@json", stringToSend);

        // This line throws the error 
        // (Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'.)
        var a = _context.Students.FromSqlRaw("[InsertWithTSQL] @json", param);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
}
```

**Student.cs**

```
public partial class Student
{
  public int? Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string RollNo { get; set; }
  public string Class { get; set; }
  public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON which i'm sending to SP**

```
'[{"Id":2,"Name":"Khan","RollNo":"23","Class":"VI","Age":21}]'
```

Comment: What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: @thommyberglund i received (Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'.)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2016 or above?

Comment: Please edit your tags specifying the SQL Server version you are using

Comment: @GSerg using sql 2019

Comment: What is your database compatibility level? [Should be 130](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @GSerg it is 130 as its working fine in SSMS.

Comment: Please double check that as in SQL Server 2019, the default compatibility level is 150. You have not shown calling the procedure from SSMS, only creating it. A stored procedure will create fine if it refers to non-existent objects, but will raise an error when called.

Comment: @GSerg i double checked it. compatibility level is 130 and also its working fine when i call Stored procedure from SSMS

Comment: Then you must be connecting to a different server from C#, or to a different database with lower compatibility level.

Comment: @GSerg no i am connecting right database im sure about this